# Content behind the status bar on Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a TableView and ImageView header on Storyboard (Xcode 9). I wonder how it is possible to set content (ImageView) behind the status bar and not below the status bar.

[image: imageView must go behind the status bar]

With this line of code I get the desired result, but I want to set this through the Storyboard.

```
tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Select your table view in your storyboard
- Open the Size Inspector (ruler tab in the right pane)
- Go to section entitled "Scroll View"
- Look for the drop down named "Content Insets"
- Open the drop down and select "Never"

[image: Content insets drop down]